# Tool to cleanup or fix pom.xml in Java - Maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

Over time the java project could be messy. Programmers add and remove libraries. They remove codes but left the `dependency` in the pom.xml untouched.

Is there a tool out there that can:

- Scan unneeded `dependency` within the pom.xml and perhaps suggest
  those entries for removal?
- To detect and fix the `scope` of a
  dependency?
- To add or suggest a dependency?

Comment: What do you mean by "fixing the scope"?

Comment: The `mvn dependency:analyze` show suggestion of the appropriate scope for example see the `provided` within `[WARNING]    org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs:jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:provided`

Comment: maven-dependency-plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `mvn dependency:analyze`. It shows you all dependencies that are in the POM, but that are not used in the source code. It furthermore lists transitive dependencies which you accidentally used as direct dependencies.

Comment: Thank you. The `mvn dependency:analyze` result is good enough. Some of the suggested result list of `Unused declared dependencies found:` is actually used, thus we need to be careful and hand-pick the result.

Answer (score 0):

In your pom.xml, add

```
   <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>analyze</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>analyze-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnWarning>true</failOnWarning>
                            <outputXML>true</outputXML>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
                                <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>xxx</ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>
                                <ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>xxx</ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependency>
                            </ignoredUnusedDeclaredDependencies>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
</plugin>
```